# Adding a blank column in union SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datasource, tableau-api

```
SELECT 
[wo#],
[COL2] as "Team"   
FROM T1
union 
select [request_external_wo_number], ' '
from T2
```

I would like to add a blank column in my tableau data source. I have this code that works fine in SSMS. However, when I transfer it to Tableau, it doesn't work. Is there a better syntax to use besides ' ' ?

[image: The error I receive in Tableau when attempting all possibilities. Everything works fine, I get output when I comment out the troublesome blank column.]

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Can you just add null instead of '' and format it on the front end?

Comment: It means I get an error and the code will not run.

Comment: Shown above. Thanks

Comment: You might want to run a sql profile and see what query you are actually executing against the server.

Comment: The error message might have something to do with incorrectly formatted code next to a CASE statement. I'm not sure it has anything to do with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just leave it by `null`

```
SELECT [wo#] as "col1", [COL2] as "Team"   
FROM T1 UNION  
SELECT [request_external_wo_number], null
FROM T2
```

This will produce blank field under `Team` column from `T2` table as you don't add extra overhead for *SQL*